# Check coordinates in polygon

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I use Google Maps api and geolocation functionalities in HTML5.
To resume : I use results of "navigator.geolocation.watchPosition" on a page displaying on a smartphone and I check if coordinates are presents in an area.

In first test, i find this function : http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-js-api-v3%40googlegroups.com/msg04561.html

And now, i discover this : [Point-in-Polygon PHP Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040671/point-in-polygon-php-errors)

So I have a javascript function and a php function that make the same job : Check a coordinate and return true/false if the coordinate is inside an area.

Is it preferable to make the verification by the javascript function (so by the mobile device) of by php function (php function used thanks to Ajax call and others of course) ?

Which method is more speed, consume less, etc. ?
For me, it's preferable to attribute the charge to a php server than a client device, but I tell the question to experts :-)

Thanks for yours answers

Answer (score 1):

If you can trust the client or if you don't care about a possible hack of the script, I would rather put the JavaScript code on the client side to avoid having a client/server request, it should give a better user experience instead of an AJAX call.

If in any case you have a client/server request and if you can combine the check within the same request then it is better in PHP.